# Calculations with Transposed Inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, transpose

Find $X$ for$\ A^T(BA^{-1}-I)^TX=B^T $ If:

$$A =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$
and
$$B =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$$

I got:
$\ X=((BA^{-1}-I)^T)^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}B^T $
However I think it's quite complicated to solve this equation in this way and I feel that there should be some way of simplifying it to some extent.

Comment: What is $E$ in the equation?

Comment: It should be $I$. My bad, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose the equation first you get
$$X^T(BA^{-1}-I)A=B\quad
  \Rightarrow\quad X^T(B-A)=B\quad
  \Rightarrow\quad X^T=B(B-A)^{-1}$$
which is not too hard to calculate.  And from $X^T$, finding $X$ is trivial.